# GitBash - can't enter a new command after starting npm

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line

The solution to my problem may be simple but since I'm a beginner on command line and npm it's been hard to solve it by myself, hopefuly you know the solution:

I cloned a repository and then started npm in the command line. After I enter the command 'start npm', it shows in console that webpack was succesfuly compiled but after no matter what I input, the command line does not execute anything neither shows an error message. I've tried to input, as I've done before, a new command but it seems to add text and not a command. (see the picture)[image: After the webpack is compiled I tried entering a new command]

Or if it is not a problem and i'm just misunderstanding something, please tell me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> After I enter the command 'start npm'

Judging by the image you provided, this command is starting the Webpack dev-server. This is a web server for testing your application, which will monitor your files and rebuild your app when any changes are detected. Once the server is running in a terminal, any further input on your part will be ignored. You can stop the server using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

> Or if it is not a problem and I'm just misunderstanding something, please tell me.

The server instance will (in its default configuration) be listening for connections from localhost on port 8080, so (depending on how your app is set up), it might now be enough to visit http://localhost:3000 in your browser to see your project running. If that's not the case, check the output in the terminal window for something like: `Project is running at http://localhost:3035/`

It might also help to have a look in `package.json` to see what else (if anything) `npm start` is doing.

Further reading: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server

Comment: I figured myself that if I opened another Git Bash window (simultaneously while the other was running the server) I could still input commands, so it's coherent with your contribution. I'll check the resources provided, thank you so much!